# Are there any Thin Client software's for WinXP that block P2P and torrent? Except server-side installation

Tags: windows-xp, thin-client, blocking, p2p

I want to block p2p and torrent connection without any firewall or server-side software installation.

Most of all it is FREE.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged with thin-client?  If you're not blocking at the firewall or the server, are you looking for a client solution?  More information about the machines generating the P2P and why you don't have the ability to block at the appropriate points in the network would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a pair of scissors somewhere; that'll block peer-to-peer software without costing anything, installing a firewall, or installing any software on a server.

Comment: You are right.., and that's the first option..., and this is only my second option..., because of cost. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Is this for a single computer, or an entire network? If its a single computer, configure the windows firewall manually. If its a network, configure the windows firewall via GPO. (IF you are running AD, that is)

You could also look into OPENDNS.com filtering as well.

Comment: +1 - this was my answer. Monitor the network traffic, determine ports and executables used for P2P, and make sure the Windows Firewall is set to block those through GPO.

Answer (score 0):

WinXP SP2 and higher has a built-in firewall. That software can be configured to block all kinds of things, and it is already paid for.

Take a look at the configure and edit your question to be more specific, I'm sure you will get more specific answers

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease [halfopen](http://half-open.com/) connections limit to minimum (i.e 1 or 2) it'll make p2p almost unusable, but also will cost you slow browsing speed

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend going with a P2P IP-Filter list. They're freely available. One in particular that I use is from:

http://blocklistpro.com/download-center/ip-filters/

And it's free. Migrate that to each users hosts file and flush the machines dns:

Start -> Run - > cmd
ipconfig /flushdns

Answer (score 0):

Get a Linksys WRT54G and put a 3rd party firmware on it (DD-WRT2.4+) that has bandwidth management functions. Then you can restrict bandwidth by port and/or ip address.